# Ваше приложение позволяет отображать пользовательский контент, но не имеет надлежащих мер предосторожности

Tags: swift, appstore

Ваше приложение позволяет отображать пользовательский контент, но не имеет надлежащих мер предосторожности.

Дальнейшие действия

Для решения этой проблемы, пожалуйста, измените ваше приложение, чтобы реализовать все следующие меры предосторожности:

- Требовать, чтобы пользователи согласились с условиями (EULA), и эти условия должны прояснить, что не допускается нежелательный контент или оскорбительные пользователи
- Метод для фильтрации нежелательного контента
- механизм для пользователей флага нежелательного контента
- механизм для пользователей , чтобы блокировать оскорбительные пользователь
- разработчик должен действовать на неугодных отчетах о содержании в течение 24 часов, удаляя содержимое и выталкивания пользователя, при условии , что содержание обижая
  Оригинал:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  Можно ли как то пройти проверку не создавая функции фильтрации контента?
  Кто сталкивался с этим?